# An error occurred while installing face_recognition Error text: Collecting face_recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, face-recognition

I want to start face recognition project on python. i installed bython and install pipenv. after this when I install " pipenv install face_recognition" shell give me a error after some installation.

(mrblack--PGk31eo) C:\Users\mrblack>

```
 pipenv install face_recognition
Installing face_recognition…
```

Error:  **An error occurred while installing face_recognition!**
Error text: Collecting face_recognition
RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions:_dlib_pybind11
Installation Failed

Answer (score 2):

From http://dlib.net/compile.html :

> Note that you need to have **CMake** and a working C++ compiler installed for this to work.

(Emphasize mine — *phd*)

Install CMake from https://cmake.org/download/ or https://pypi.org/project/cmake/. Try `pip install cmake`

Comment: can I use any C++ compiler instead of VS C++

Comment: At http://dlib.net/compile.html see the section **Compiling on Windows Using GCC**

Comment: from these when I type cmake --build . --config Release
i recived these error
Error: could not load cache

Comment: I install VS c++ compailer and Cmake in Windows 10 succesfully but when I want to install dlib after cmake i get this error "You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
  are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
  that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
  development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++" although I already install Visual Studio C++. what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

For installing face-recognition module for Ubuntu 18.04: (Try for other OS, I used this for 18.04)

Install cmake: `pip install cmake`
After cmake is successfully installed

Optional: Install git if you don't have git

```
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
```

build the main dlib library

```
cd dlib mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; cmake --build .
```

Build and install python essentials

```
cd .. python3 setup.py install
```

After all this run these to verify

```
python3 
import dlib
```

Now install face_recognition

```
pip3 install face_recognition
```

Takes some time but that is okay! I hope it worked for you

Refer these materials:

face-recognition original repo: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#installing-on-mac-or-linux
dlib: https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf

Answer (score 1):

face_recognition package requires dlib and it is a very huge package and problematic in installation. I recommend you to adopt deepface package for face recognition. It is mainly based on Keras and TensorFlow. In other words, it is easy to make initial setup.

Besides, it wraps dlib and some other state-of-the-art face recognition models: VGG-Face (University of Oxford), FaceNet (Google), OpenFace (Carneige Mellon University), DeepFace (Facebook ) and DeepID (The Chienese University of Hong Kong). I recommend you to use VGG-Face or FaceNet models.

You should just pass image pairs as exact paths. BTW, you can pass base64 encoded images or direct numpy arrays as image pairs.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID']
result  = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
print(result["verified"])
```

Result object stores the found distance and required distance threshold to verify an image pair.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when I tried it. I resolved it by degrading to **python3.7**.

So follow these steps :

1. degrade or upgrade to python3.7
2. `pip3 install CMake`
3. `pip3 install face-recognition`

these steps will resolve the error but after that when I was using the library in my code it was again giving an error related to algorithmia.
So I resolved it by downloading visual studio 2017

Hope it was helpful, 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error this worked for me:

- You have to install make and dlib before installing face recognition.

  ```
    pip3 install cmake
    pip3 install dlib 
    pip3 install face-recognition
  ```
- If this doesn't work you could use Visual Studio Code as idle.